# How do I get the drive label from the drive letter in Windows 10 in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, terminal, cmd.exe, drive-letter

I truly cannot believe I have to ask this, but after searching countless times and finding ***nothing*** online on how to do this, I must ask.

I already know about the "label" command. While it does output the label if you do:

```
label H:
```

... the purpose of the command is to change/set it -- not read it, so it asks for input in the end, and there are no flags to turn that off, so it sadly cannot be used. I have looked in:

```
label /?
```

Basically, forget about that command. I need something which outputs the label for the drive letter and then stops.

Comment: `Echo. | label c:`

Answer (score 2):

Like the comment from Mark:

`<nul label c:`

or even without tricks

```
vol c:
```